# How do I create certificates for both ends of an stunnel connection?

Tags: rdp, openssl, stunnel

I am using stunnel to authenticate RDP (Remote Desktop) and I need to verify that a **client** possesses the proper credentials. So people cannot brute force into the machine. I am also using a bad (outdated) version of RDP that has security vulnerabilities, so stunnel is a must.

I will preshare the necessary `.pem`'s between machines.

What are the `openssl` commands I need
to create the right `.pem` files on
both the client and on the server? What files need to be shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the documentation on the stunnel site that @Christian pointed at, there's lot of information out there about using `openssl` to generate certificates.  A google search for [openssl certificate authority](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=openssl+certificate+authority) will get you links to a variety of useful tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your questions are answered by the [stunnel FAQ](http://www.stunnel.org/faq/certs.html).

There is also a [special page](http://www.stunnel.org/examples/client_cert.html) on client certificates.

Comment: these docs are poorly written / not well explained. It is difficult for me to follow.

Comment: as you accepted an answer, it seems you now have your solution. Perhaps you can enhance the stunnel documentation at the points where you had problems. This might help some other people getting the same problems.